# Поменять формат даты в momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Задача: Поменять формат даты.
Что имеем:
Спарсили дату в момент js

```
var data2 = moment("8 декабря, 2017", "D MMM, YYYY");
```

Вопрос, как получить дату следующего типа 8.12.2017?
Можно конечно извращаться и вычлинять дни, меся и неделю по отдельности, но хочется более адекватное решение. спс

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var string = data2.format("DD.MM.YY");
```

Вернет строку нужного формата

```
string === '08.12.17'
```

Comment: Примите ответ, чтобы не вопрос не висел как не решенный :)